# How to update value in ndarray by index that is inside another array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

For example, I have 10x7 ndarray of zeros `x=np.zeros( (10,7) )`

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

and I want to randomly assign one '1' in each row. Say I create another array (10,1) and then value is between 0-6. `r=np.random.randint(0, 7, (10,1))`

```
array([[6],
       [2],
       [5],
       [1],
       [2],
       [4],
       [6],
       [3],
       [0],
       [1]])
```

i want from `r` that it means set to 0 of the element x[0,6] , x[1,2], x[2,5], x[3,1] etc, so x should become something like

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

How to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a one dimensional array for `r` and use it as the column index. For row indexes you can simply use a range:

```
In [25]: r=np.random.randint(0, 7, 10)

In [26]: x=np.zeros( (10,7) )

In [27]: x[np.arange(10), r] = 1

In [28]: x
Out[28]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: or directly: `x[np.arange(x.shape[0]), r] = 1`